# Why overriding the `__get__` method of a class in Python affects what is returned?

Tags: python, class, oop

In this code snippet, overriding the `__get__` method of `Book` class changes what is being returned in the `BookManager` when calling `Book`.

When `__get__` is override to return a dict, `book_1` is a `dict`. While `book_2` defined within the `__init__` of `BookManager` returns an instance of `Book`, and **not a dict**.

If I comment out `__get__` in class `Book`, then both `book_1` and `book_2` inside `BookManager` become instances of `Book`.

Could someone explain what is the underlying reason for this behavior?

```
class Book:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    return {'name': self.name}


class BookManager:
  book_1 = Book('python') # a dict is returned

  def __init__(self, book_name):
    self.book_2 = Book(book_name) # an instance of the object is returned


class Library:
  def __init__(self):
    self.book_manager = BookManager('javascript')
```

**Output**

```
>> l = Library()
>> l.book_manager.book_1
{'name': 'python'}
>> l.book_manager.book_2
<__main__.Book object at 0x7f56adf11278>
```

Comment: Also, see https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/descriptor.html.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I am struggling to find my answer. Depending on where an instance of `Book` is created, a different type is returned. Could you explain how does this relate to descriptor?

Comment: `book_1` isn't an instance attribute; it's a *class* attribute. When `foo.book1` is evaluated, the result is seen to have a `__get__` method, so instead of getting back `type(foo).__dict__['book1']`, you get `type(foo).__dict__['book1'].__get__(foo, type(foo)`. The descriptor protocol doesn't apply to instance attributes.